# close one modal and open a new modal with one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using *bootstrap* and have a **one** modal that I would like to have a link on to **another** modal. I can't seem to figure this out and currently I am using the `modal.close()`and `.modal('show')` but that is not working.

```
$('a#to3heart').click(function(){
    $('#portfolioModal2').modal({onShow: function (dialog) {
        $.modal.close()
        $('#portfolioModal1').modal('show'); 
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle of your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
$("#modal1").modal('hide');
$("#modal2").modal('show');
```

see: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5qCm9/**

Comment: thanks so much. and sorry if this was a stupid question

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above answers posted ,none of them seems to work in my case finally,i wrote this .
This will hide any active modal on your screen and show the only clicked modal

```
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function() { 
    
        $('.modal').not($(this).data('target')).modal('hide');
   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it with a generic jQuery solution.

It just hides all modal that are not targeted.

```
$('button[data-target]').click(function () {
    $('.modal').not($(this).data('target')).modal('hide');
});
```